# Cached external image component flickers on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

For the purposes of this question, imagine there are only two top-level components -- a side nav and a top nav. The side nav changes the routes and the top nav has an avatar image in the top right that comes from an external source. The top nav is not nested in the side nav as you can see here:

```
<>
        <SideNav profile={profile}/>
        <TopNav />

        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/app" component={App} />
          <Route exact path="/app/profile" component={UserProfileMain} />
          <Route path="/app/profile/preferences" component={UserProfilePrefs} />
          <Route path="/app/profile/notifications" component={UserProfileNotifs} />
          <Route path="/app/profile/billing" component={UserProfileBilling} />
        </Switch>
      </>
```

However, when I use the SideNav to switch to another route (e.g. from /app/profile to app/profile/preferences), the Avatar component flickers. I checked my Network tab of the DevTools and it is loading the image again from the cache every time I change routes. I assume this means the TopNav component is somehow re-rendering, but given that it is outside of the  I am not sure why it would do so.

TopNav:

```
const TopNav = () => (
  <Nav>
    <LeftNav>
      <PageTitle>Page Title</PageTitle>
    </LeftNav>
    <RightNav>
      <NavSpacer1>
        <NotificationsIcon />
      </NavSpacer1>
      <NavSpacer2>
        <InboxIcon />
      </NavSpacer2>
      <AvatarWrapper justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <Avatar src="path/to/the/file" small />
      </AvatarWrapper>
    </RightNav>
  </Nav>
)
```

A link from SideNav.js:

```
  <StyledMenuItem disableGutters={true} >
            <StyledLink to="/app/profile">
              <LinkContent alignItems="center">
                <P noMargin>My Profile & Plan</P>
              </LinkContent>
            </StyledLink>
          </StyledMenuItem>
```